# Kaazing Configuration

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, amqp, qpid, kaazing

Hi i want to achieve  one setup as stated below but facing some issues while configuring the same.

Kaazing JMS edition integration with AMQP 1.0 architecture ( Apache Qpid JMS AMQP 1.0 Client) centered around ActiveMQ. Can you please suggest.

What i have done, is i have copied the lib/ files(.jar) provided with apache Qpid amqp 1.0 client  into kaazing`s lib directory now i have to create a connection factory configuration in gateway config.xml. How can i create new configuration and what would i do with old configuration already there in gateway-config.xml

Current Configuration which is connection to ActiveMQ using openwire tcp protocol.

jms

```
<properties>
  <connection.factory.name>ConnectionFactory</connection.factory.name>
  <context.lookup.topic.format>dynamicTopics/%s</context.lookup.topic.format>
  <context.lookup.queue.format>dynamicQueues/%s</context.lookup.queue.format>
  <env.java.naming.factory.initial>org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</env.java.naming.factory.initial>
  <env.java.naming.provider.url>tcp://${gateway.hostname}:61616</env.java.naming.provider.url>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comment the default configuration and can use the below configurations to integrate kaazing JMS to active MQ using qpid amqp 1.0 client library. I assume amqp port is set to 5672 only in active-ma configurations and all supported jar libraries are copied into kaazing`s lib directory.

```
<connection.factory.name>qpidConnectionFactory</connection.factory.name>  
<context.lookup.topic.format>dynamicTopics/%s</context.lookup.topic.format>  
<context.lookup.queue.format>dynamicQueues/%s</context.lookup.queue.format>
<env.java.naming.factory.initial>org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContex tFactory</env.java.naming.factory.initial>
<env.java.naming.provider.url>GATEWAY_HOME/bin/qpid_jndi.properties</env.java.naming.provider. url>  
<destination.strategy>session</destination.strategy>
```